# How to attach logs/outputs to an alert in Slack using the Slack-Opsgenie integration?

Tags: slack, opsgenie

When we get alerts in Opsgenie about a process-failure, it sends the alert to slack using the integration.
The opsgenie GUI also has a "Details" tab which has the description of the process. Is it possible to attach this description as a file attachment and send the attachment along with the alert to slack?